# how to run one java aplication JFrame on Ubuntu Server with Xinit

Tags: 18.04, java, xinit

I`m trying to run one java jframe aplication on Ubuntu Server with xinit, it is possible? I tried to run the java aplication with:

```
startx java -jar myapp.jar
```

but I receive the next messages

[image]

And these are the warning messages in the log

```
[   601.694] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   601.694]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   601.694] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   601.694]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   601.694] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   601.694]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   601.694] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   601.694]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   601.694] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   601.715] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   601.715] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   601.715] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   601.719] (WW) vmware(0): Failed to initialize Gallium3D Xa. No render acceleration available.
[   601.719] (WW) vmware(0): Skipped initialization of direct rendering due to lack of render acceleration.
[   601.720] (WW) vmware(0): Disabling Xv because no adaptors could be initialized.
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the log with the complete file